# Maximum and Minimum value $|z|$, given $|2z + 3i| = |z^2|$

Tags: complex-numbers

Let $z = a + ib$ (where $a,b \in R$ and $i=\sqrt{-1}$) such that $|2z + 3i| = |z^2|$, Then find the value of $|z|_{max}$ and $|z|_{min}$

My concept, I used $z = a + ib$, hence $|2a+i(2b+3)| = |a^2-b^2+i2ab|$.

On solving I am getting  $4a^2+(2b+3)^2 = (a^2+b^2)^2$ , from here I cannot proceed

Answer (score 2):

Making $z = \rho e^{i\phi}$ we have

$$
\rho^2 = \sqrt{4\rho^2+12\rho\sin\phi+9}
$$

or

$$
\rho^4 = 4\rho^2+12\rho\sin\phi+9
$$

now making the lagrangian

$$
L(\rho,\phi,\lambda) = \rho-\lambda(4\rho^2+12\rho\sin\phi+9-\rho^4)
$$

the stationary conditions give

$$
\nabla L = 0 = \left\{
\begin{array}{l}
 \lambda  \left(4 \rho ^3-8 \rho -12 \sin (\phi )\right)+1 \\
 -12 \lambda  \rho  \cos (\phi ) \\
 \rho ^4-4 \rho ^2-12 \sin (\phi ) \rho -9 \\
\end{array}
\right.
$$

and solving we get at

$$
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
\rho & \phi & \lambda\\
 1 & -\frac{\pi }{2} & -\frac{1}{8} \\
 3 & \frac{\pi }{2} & -\frac{1}{72} \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$

NOTE

$$
 \rho ^4-4 \rho ^2-12 \rho -9 =(\rho+1)(\rho-3)(\rho^2+2\rho+3)\\
 \rho ^4-4 \rho ^2+12 \rho -9 =(\rho-1)(\rho+3)(\rho^2-2\rho+3)
$$